# How to get function for show and hide to work on each set of div

Tags: jquery

How can I make the `onclick` function just show and hide the contents within each div? This simply hides both sets of divs.

```js
function Divshow() {
  $('.show_div').hide();
  $('.hide_div').show();
  $('.show_hide').show();
}

function DivHide() {
  $('.hide_div').hide();
  $('.show_div').show();
  $('.show_hide').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <a onclick="Divshow()" class="show_div">Show</a>
    <a onclick="DivHide()" class="hide_div" style="display:none">Hide</a>
  </div>
  <div class="show_hide" style="display:none">Text</div>
  <div class="show_hide" style="display:none">Text2</div>
  <div class="show_hide" style="display:none">Text3</div>
  <div class="show_hide" style="display:none">Text4</div>
  <div class="show_hide" style="display:none">Text5</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <a onclick="Divshow()" class="show_div">Show</a>
    <a onclick="DivHide()" class="hide_div" style="display:none">Hide</a>
  </div>
  <div class="show_hide" style="display:none">Text</div>
  <div class="show_hide" style="display:none">Text2</div>
  <div class="show_hide" style="display:none">Text3</div>
  <div class="show_hide" style="display:none">Text4</div>
  <div class="show_hide" style="display:none">Text5</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g7zw5q2c/

Comment: Wrap both blocks with parent div like block1p,block2p then onclick do something like $('block1p'). children('show_div').hide()/show(). If it's not working then use each() function

Comment: @abhay while that's a workable solution, it's not very extensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a class for each "groups", your can refer to it to find the releveant elements.

You can have the same class for both "togglers"... Then just `.toggle()` both classes found within the "group".

```js
$(".show_hide_toggler").on("click", function(){
  let group = $(this).closest(".group")
  group.find(".show_hide").toggle()
  group.find(".show_hide_toggler").toggle()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group">
  <div>
    <a class="show_hide_toggler">Show</a>
    <a class="show_hide_toggler" style="display:none">Hide</a>
  </div>
  <div class="show_hide" style="display:none">Text</div>
  <div class="show_hide" style="display:none">Text2</div>
  <div class="show_hide" style="display:none">Text3</div>
  <div class="show_hide" style="display:none">Text4</div>
  <div class="show_hide" style="display:none">Text5</div>
</div>

<div class="group">
  <div>
    <a class="show_hide_toggler">Show</a>
    <a class="show_hide_toggler" style="display:none">Hide</a>
  </div>
  <div class="show_hide" style="display:none">Text</div>
  <div class="show_hide" style="display:none">Text2</div>
  <div class="show_hide" style="display:none">Text3</div>
  <div class="show_hide" style="display:none">Text4</div>
  <div class="show_hide" style="display:none">Text5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you need you require a reference to the clicked element so that you can find the elements in the DOM which relate to it. This is possible using an `onclick` attribute, however use of them is no longer considered best practice.

A better method is to attach your event handlers unobtrusively. As you've included jQuery in the page already this can be done very easily by using the `on()` method. From there you can select the relevant elements (note that I added some extra classes where necessary to make this step easier) and then just `toggle()` their visibility.

With all that said, try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.show_div, .hide_div').on('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let $this = $(e.target);
    let $sibling = $this.siblings();
    $(e.target).closest('.container').find('div:not(.toggle)').add($this).add($sibling).toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.show_hide,
.hide_div { 
  display: none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="toggle">
    <a href="#" class="show_div">Show</a>
    <a href="#" class="hide_div">Hide</a>
  </div>
  <div class="show_hide">Text</div>
  <div class="show_hide">Text2</div>
  <div class="show_hide">Text3</div>
  <div class="show_hide">Text4</div>
  <div class="show_hide">Text5</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="toggle">
    <a href="#" class="show_div">Show</a>
    <a href="#" class="hide_div">Hide</a>
  </div>
  <div class="show_hide">Text</div>
  <div class="show_hide">Text2</div>
  <div class="show_hide">Text3</div>
  <div class="show_hide">Text4</div>
  <div class="show_hide">Text5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the div containing each section add an id so you can differentiate between the two sections. Then you can pass the id into the `DivShow()` function as a parameter and use it to access the elements in that div.

```js
function Divshow(divname) {
    $(divname + ' .show_div').hide();
    $(divname + ' .hide_div').show();
    $(divname + ' .show_hide').show();
  }  
  function DivHide() {
    $('.hide_div').hide();
    $('.show_div').show();
    $('.show_hide').hide();
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="topdiv">
    <div>
        <a onclick="Divshow('#topdiv')" class="show_div">Show</a>
        <a onclick="DivHide()" class="hide_div" style="display:none">Hide</a>
    </div>
    <div class="div1 show_hide" style="display:none">Text</div>
    <div class="div1 show_hide" style="display:none">Text2</div>
    <div class="div1 show_hide" style="display:none">Text3</div>
    <div class="div1 show_hide" style="display:none">Text4</div>
    <div class="div1 show_hide" style="display:none">Text5</div>
</div>

<div id="bottomdiv">
    <div>
        <a onclick="Divshow('#bottomdiv')" class="show_div">Show</a>
        <a onclick="DivHide()" class="hide_div" style="display:none">Hide</a>
    </div>
    <div class="show_hide" style="display:none">Text</div>
    <div class="show_hide" style="display:none">Text2</div>
    <div class="show_hide" style="display:none">Text3</div>
    <div class="show_hide" style="display:none">Text4</div>
    <div class="show_hide" style="display:none">Text5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep your HTML, CSS and JS separate.

To keep the event hander actions within the target `div`, `this`, the clicked element has to be the reference point.

```
$('div > div > a').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('div').find('a').toggle();
    const txt = this.textContent.trim().toLowerCase();
    $(this).closest('div').siblings()[txt]();
});
```

```js
$('div > div > a').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('div').find('a').toggle();
    const txt = this.textContent.trim().toLowerCase();
    $(this).closest('div').siblings()[txt]();
});
```

```css
.hide_div, .show_hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <a class="show_div">Show</a>
    <a class="hide_div">Hide</a>
  </div>
  <div class="show_hide">Text</div>
  <div class="show_hide">Text2</div>
  <div class="show_hide">Text3</div>
  <div class="show_hide">Text4</div>
  <div class="show_hide">Text5</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <a class="show_div">Show</a>
    <a class="hide_div">Hide</a>
  </div>
  <div class="show_hide">Text</div>
  <div class="show_hide">Text2</div>
  <div class="show_hide">Text3</div>
  <div class="show_hide">Text4</div>
  <div class="show_hide">Text5</div>
</div>
```